# Multiple mariadb instances - how to access to the not default instances via command line?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.1

I have a TYPO3 and a Moodle installation on one server with Debian stretch.

Moodle needs some database configurations (MariaDB 10.1.38) which are different from the ones TYPO3 needs.

I made a new configuration `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mymoodle.cnf` (with port 3307 and datadir `/var/lib/mysql-moodle`), installed the default DBs in the new datadir with

```
mkdir /var/lib/mysql-moodle
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql-moodle
mysql_install_db --datadir=/var/lib/mysql-moodle
```

and started the instance with

```
service mariadb@moodle start
```

Obviously this works:

```
# ps aux | grep mysql
mysql    14135  0.1  1.8 678184 74032 ?        Ssl  Jun25   1:20 /usr/sbin/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/conf.d/mymoodle.cnf
mysql    14323  4.8  6.1 720344 241200 ?       Ssl  Jun25  55:03 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root     25475  0.0  0.0  12712   880 pts/0    S+   14:06   0:00 grep mysql

# netstat -tulpen | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      107        76817214   14323/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3307          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      107        76816770   14135/mysqld
```

That's looks good, I thought, but I didn't find an access via command line. Calling the client with

```
mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/conf.d/mymoodle.cnf --port 3307
```

leads me to the default instance:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%datadir%';
```

gives me `/var/lib/mysql` instead of `/var/lib/mysql-moodle`.

What is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [manual says](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql-command-line-client/):

> If hostname is not specified or hostname is localhost, then Unix sockets are used. Unused connection parameters (such as port) will be ignored.

To override the default behaviour, use either the `--protocol` option to use TCP

```
mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/conf.d/mymoodle.cnf --port 3307 --protocol tcp
```

or the `--socket` option to direct it to the second instance's socket (I assume you have specified a different socket in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mymoodle.cnf`

Comment: Problem solved for me with  `--protocol tcp`. Thank you. I was thinking that the socket defined in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mymoodle.cnf` will be the choice because of `--defaults-file=/etc/mysql/conf.d/mymoodle.cnf`. That was obviously wrong.

Comment: Now I know why `--defaults-file=/etc/mysql/conf.d/mymoodle.cnf` was not enough. The socket definition `socket= /var/run/mysqld/mysqld-moodle.sock` was only in section   `[mysqld]`  but not in `[mysql]`. With socket defintion in `[mysql]` i don't need protocol nor socket option in command line.